# Center 3 floating divs inside a wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs inline a wrapper div. i want all three divs to be in the center of the 100% width wrapper div.

i tried `margin: 0 auto` but it didn't work because of the 100% width.

here is the code:

```
#first, #next, #last {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}



#content #kompetenzen {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and the html

```
<div id="kompetenzen">
    <div id="first">

        <img src="images/kompetenzen/graphic.png" alt="Werbegrafik" />
        <ul>
            <h3>HEADER</h3>
            <br>
            <li>LEISTUNG1</li>
            <li>LEISTUNG2</li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="next">

        <img src="images/kompetenzen/design.png" alt="Werbegrafik" />
        <ul>
            <h3>HEADER</h3>
            <br>
            <li>LEISTUNG1</li>
            <li>LEISTUNG2</li>
            <li>LEISTUNG3</li>
            <li>LEISTUNG4</li>


        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="last">
        <img src="images/kompetenzen/dev.png" alt="Werbegrafik" />
        <ul>
            <h3>HEADER</h3>
            <br>
            <li>LEISTUNG1</li>
            <li>LEISTUNG2</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML. I will try to work this out in a fiddle, but I need HTML.

Comment: your html? centered horiz. in content div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `float:left` from the `#first` etc., and replace it with a `display:inline-block;`

```
#first, #next, #last {
    width: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}



#kompetenzen {
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/70e2uqc1/1/

Comment: it should center in screen (#kompetenzen is width: 100%) --> screensize

Comment: There was no `#content`, so the css selector `#content #kompetenzen` did not work.

Comment: if they have different content, they dont stay in line :S

Answer (score 1):

`#content #kompetenzen` could use `display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content: center`. This would make 3 divs vertically and horizontally centered.
**UPDATE**
Be aware of browser compatibility and use vendor prefixes properly.

Comment: BTW, if that helped you, please accept the answer. thanks!

Comment: the items are centered now. but the problem is i want the divs to stack if the browserwidth gehts smaller (or mobile).. it doesnt work anymore with this code

Comment: Just add #first, #second, #third { width:33% }, that would make them always stack in the middle. Also use @media queries if necessary.

Comment: @ThomasKlammer then don't use fixed dimensions, in `px` but in `%`. and watch out for paddings, margins too.